# How can i change the keybinds to open devtools with js in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

so you can disable and enable devtools in electron in `main` or `index.js`.
if the devtools are disabled they can still be accessed by pressings `ctrl + shift + i`
is it possible to change these keybinds to something else with js?

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut key of Developer Tools is bound to the Menu, so if you want to change this shortcut key, you need to create a Menu yourself.
Here is some code for your reference.

```js
import { app, Menu, shell, BrowserWindow, MenuItemConstructorOptions } from 'electron';

interface DarwinMenuItemConstructorOptions extends MenuItemConstructorOptions {
  selector?: string;
  submenu?: DarwinMenuItemConstructorOptions[] | Menu;
}

export default class MenuBuilder {
  mainWindow: BrowserWindow;

  constructor(mainWindow: BrowserWindow) {
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
  }

  buildMenu(): Menu {
    const template =
      process.platform === 'darwin' ? this.buildDarwinTemplate() : this.buildDefaultTemplate();

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    return menu;
  }

  buildDarwinTemplate(): MenuItemConstructorOptions[] {
    const subMenuAbout: DarwinMenuItemConstructorOptions = {
      label: 'Electron',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'About ElectronReact',
          selector: 'orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:',
        },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { label: 'Services', submenu: [] },
        { type: 'separator' },
        {
          label: 'Hide ElectronReact',
          accelerator: 'Command+H',
          selector: 'hide:',
        },
        {
          label: 'Hide Others',
          accelerator: 'Command+Shift+H',
          selector: 'hideOtherApplications:',
        },
        { label: 'Show All', selector: 'unhideAllApplications:' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        {
          label: 'Quit',
          accelerator: 'Command+Q',
          click: () => {
            app.quit();
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const subMenuEdit: DarwinMenuItemConstructorOptions = {
      label: 'Edit',
      submenu: [
        { label: 'Undo', accelerator: 'Command+Z', selector: 'undo:' },
        { label: 'Redo', accelerator: 'Shift+Command+Z', selector: 'redo:' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { label: 'Cut', accelerator: 'Command+X', selector: 'cut:' },
        { label: 'Copy', accelerator: 'Command+C', selector: 'copy:' },
        { label: 'Paste', accelerator: 'Command+V', selector: 'paste:' },
        {
          label: 'Select All',
          accelerator: 'Command+A',
          selector: 'selectAll:',
        },
      ],
    };
    const subMenuViewDev: MenuItemConstructorOptions = {
      label: 'View',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Reload',
          accelerator: 'Command+R',
          click: () => {
            this.mainWindow.webContents.reload();
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Toggle Full Screen',
          accelerator: 'Ctrl+Command+F',
          click: () => {
            this.mainWindow.setFullScreen(!this.mainWindow.isFullScreen());
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Toggle Developer Tools',
          accelerator: 'Alt+Command+I',
          click: () => {
            this.mainWindow.webContents.toggleDevTools();
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const subMenuViewProd: MenuItemConstructorOptions = {
      label: 'View',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Toggle Full Screen',
          accelerator: 'Ctrl+Command+F',
          click: () => {
            this.mainWindow.setFullScreen(!this.mainWindow.isFullScreen());
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const subMenuWindow: DarwinMenuItemConstructorOptions = {
      label: 'Window',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Minimize',
          accelerator: 'Command+M',
          selector: 'performMiniaturize:',
        },
        { label: 'Close', accelerator: 'Command+W', selector: 'performClose:' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { label: 'Bring All to Front', selector: 'arrangeInFront:' },
      ],
    };
    const subMenuHelp: MenuItemConstructorOptions = {
      label: 'Help',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Learn More',
          click() {
            shell.openExternal('https://electronjs.org');
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Documentation',
          click() {
            shell.openExternal('https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/main/docs#readme');
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Community Discussions',
          click() {
            shell.openExternal('https://www.electronjs.org/community');
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Search Issues',
          click() {
            shell.openExternal('https://github.com/electron/electron/issues');
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    const subMenuView =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
        ? subMenuViewDev
        : subMenuViewProd;

    return [subMenuAbout, subMenuEdit, subMenuView, subMenuWindow, subMenuHelp];
  }

  buildDefaultTemplate() {
    const templateDefault = [
      {
        label: '&File',
        submenu: [
          {
            label: '&Open',
            accelerator: 'Ctrl+O',
          },
          {
            label: '&Close',
            accelerator: 'Ctrl+W',
            click: () => {
              this.mainWindow.close();
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: '&View',
        submenu:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
            ? [
                {
                  label: '&Reload',
                  accelerator: 'Ctrl+R',
                  click: () => {
                    this.mainWindow.webContents.reload();
                  },
                },
                {
                  label: 'Toggle &Full Screen',
                  accelerator: 'F11',
                  click: () => {
                    this.mainWindow.setFullScreen(!this.mainWindow.isFullScreen());
                  },
                },
                {
                  label: 'Toggle &Developer Tools',
                  accelerator: 'Alt+Ctrl+I',
                  click: () => {
                    this.mainWindow.webContents.toggleDevTools();
                  },
                },
              ]
            : [
                {
                  label: 'Toggle &Full Screen',
                  accelerator: 'F11',
                  click: () => {
                    this.mainWindow.setFullScreen(!this.mainWindow.isFullScreen());
                  },
                },
              ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Help',
        submenu: [
          {
            label: 'Learn More',
            click() {
              shell.openExternal('https://electronjs.org');
            },
          },
          {
            label: 'Documentation',
            click() {
              shell.openExternal('https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/main/docs#readme');
            },
          },
          {
            label: 'Community Discussions',
            click() {
              shell.openExternal('https://www.electronjs.org/community');
            },
          },
          {
            label: 'Search Issues',
            click() {
              shell.openExternal('https://github.com/electron/electron/issues');
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    return templateDefault;
  }
}
```

You can modify the shortcut key of Toggle Developer Tools, which is the accelerator parameter.

Here is how to use it in main.

```js
app
  .whenReady()
  .then(async () => {
// some code to create mainWindow
    const menu = new MenuBuilder(mainWindow).buildMenu();
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```